# Can we make a internet based Java Swing GUI?

Tags: java, swing

Made a java Swing GUI which shows Standard Time. How can it be connected to internet? I mean I want to show the same GUI in other PC located remotely.

Java code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class DigitalTimer implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame f=new JFrame("DiGi ClOcK");    
    JLabel l;
    JLabel l2;
    public DigitalTimer()
    {
    
        f.setSize(250,150);
        Font font=new Font("Arial",Font.ITALIC,24);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel clk = new JPanel();
        clk.setLayout(new BoxLayout(clk,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        f.add(clk);
        l = new JLabel();
        l2=new JLabel();
        clk.add(l2);
        clk.add(l); 
        Timer refresher = new Timer(1000,this);
        refresher.start();
        l2.setFont(font);
        l2.setText("HH:MM:SS");
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        DigitalTimer dTimer;
        dTimer = new DigitalTimer();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
    
        f.setVisible(true);
        Font font1=new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,26);
        Calendar calendar;
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour;
        hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int min;
        min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int sec;
        sec = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        l.setFont(font1);
        l.setText(hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: GUI output]

How to show the  *DigitalTimer* GUI in a remote access, if possible using database?

Comment: Remote access... like... a web page?

Comment: You gotta crawl before you can walk. This seems a bit advantageous.

Comment: *"if possible using database?"* That's like trying to crush a mosquito with an elephant. Use sockets to connect the apps. But judging by the code, which would best be tossed out before (doing the relevant tutorial &) starting fresh, you have a long way to go before *adding* any sort of remote functionality.

Comment: In case anyone comes across this question, this Webswing webserver seems to be designed to run Swing applications on web browsers.  https://www.webswing.org/docs/

Comment: Thanks Gilbert  for helping.